# How can I turn on secure boot after installing Ubuntu with secure boot off?

Tags: nvidia, uefi, secure-boot

When I install the Ubuntu 19.10 I cannot turn on secure boot when I boot from the USB key which contains the installation medium (because I used grub2 to chain-load the Ubuntu live cd).

After than I cannot load nvidia drivers when the secure boot is turned on in BIOS. This seems to be because the secure boot is off the installer did not go through all the mok generation steps described in [How can I install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 with secure boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048135/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-with-secure-boot). Normally if there is a mok key enrolled, when installing the nvidia drivers it will prompt to give some passwords and next boot will be in `mok manager`.

I wonder what the steps are now to do shim sign and enable secure boot again with the nvidia drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install Nvidia drivers ubuntu 18.04 with secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048135/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-with-secure-boot)

Comment: That one is exactly opposite. He installed the Ubuntu with secure boot turned on. As I described I knew how to do it since it is the normal we. I installed with secure boot turned off. Now I want to enable it after the system installed.

Comment: If secure boot is enabled in the BIOS, and you remove the NVidia drivers, and then boot and check `bootctl status` in the console, does it not say secure boot is enabled? If so, then you would be at the same point as the other question. If not, have you installed any other additional kernel modules that are unsigned? If not to that, then you likely have a deeper issue to deal with.

Comment: Do not know for sure, but I think you have to first create your key. Then when you re-enable nVidia, it will ask for key. Also see at bottom manual mode: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS