# How to avoid disabling secure boot every time when dual booting Ubuntu in a laptop with Nvidia GPU?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

A while ago I installed Ubuntu on my Windows machine (Asus ROG GL503GE), which has an Nvidia GPU. In order for that GPU to work when booting into Ubuntu, I have to manually disable secure boot every time. Otherwise all my GPU heavy apps would struggle to run using integrated Intel GPU. How do I enable Nvidia GPU in Ubuntu without having to disable secure boot every time when booting?

Comment: After changing Secure Boot in your BIOS, are you sure that you're saving those changes before/when leaving the BIOS?

Comment: Do you want secure boot to be on, or wanting to disable secure boot for every boot, windows and ubuntu?

Comment: @crip659 I want secure boot to be on for every boot, but I want dGPU to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can see this since you want secure boot on.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048135/how-can-i-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-secure-boot